# Swift & Firestore: AppDelegate and ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access my data in Firestore from my iOS app. 
I installed **Firebase/Firestore** pod, and built the project again. Then, I inserted the following code in **AppDelegate.swift**:

```
import Firebase

FirebaseApp.configure()

let db = Firestore.firestore()
```

Going back to my **ViewController**, i tried to access db to get some data:

```
    let services = db.collection("services").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }

        guard let docs = snapshot?.documents else { return }

        for doc in docs {
            print(doc.data())
        }
    }
```

But I get the following error: **Use of unresolved identifier 'db'**

If i move the following line to my ViewController everything is fine:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Then what you are expecting ? `db` is property of AppDelegate Class then it will be accessible with that object only

Comment: I agree, but this is in Firebase documentation and i found it confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because any declared property in a class can only be accessible from that class objects. Unless you make it static.

So if you want to be able to access you db you have two options:

- Declare it as a static property in the AppDelegate class.
- Declare it in the view controller class which is absolutely fine.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart should specify better instructions.

Answer (score 1):

**Make New Class called "GlobalFunctions.swift"**

```
import Firebase

class GlobalFunctions: NSObject {
   static let db = Firestore.firestore()
}
```

You can use this class in whole application where ever you need it like below:

```
let services = GlobalFunctions.db.collection("services").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }

        guard let docs = snapshot?.documents else { return }

        for doc in docs {
            print(doc.data())
        }
    }
```